# Where should I store ports? Simple Java application, Spring boot, maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, port, profile

For local testing my app i use port 8080, but on AWS server need to use 5000.

I propose i need to have 2 profiles, for example application.yml and application_dev.yml.
application.yml - port: 5000
application-dev.yml - port 8080

When i'll start app local with IDEA, run/debug configuration -> Active profile, write dev and that all.   My app will start with port 8080.
[Local IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeVEc.png)

With AWS server i use jar file, i upload builded jar file.

So...
I checked :) jar file has both yml files.
...
How correctly start app?

1. I do nothing and my app will start with default profile application.yml with port 5000
2. I should add something on server... i don't know... for example in Environment properties ... spring_profile application.yml. Now i use SERVER_PORT 5000  record.
   [AWS server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCCDQ.png)

Sorry, it's my first question...
And i know my English sucks.
Thanks for your time and kindness.

I'd like be glad for any information and links to articles on the topic.

I tried to create application.yml and applitation-dev.yml.

I don't tried to launch these on AWS server.

Comment: "*Where should I store ports?*" - [In the environment (`12factors.net`)](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: Isn't the exactly the behaviour you want? That it starts with port 5000 when deployed? What's the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: I added port 5000 on the server manually via the aws web interface.
I would like the server to automatically read the settings from the file that are intended specifically for it, and not for local launch.
 
If I delete the entry on the server with port 5000. Will the server understand from the application.yml file that it needs to use 5000, or does it read port 8080 from apprilaction-dev.yml?

And how correct is it to use application.yml for such things.

Now I will read the article that you left, maybe it will become easier for me to understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want your application to start with a different port, you cand add a profile customization as you did, for instance:

application-prod.yaml

```
server:
  port: 50000
```

Than start it activating the correct profile :

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar target/your-app.jar
```

And the application will override the port.

Of course you can use the opposite approch, set the default port for production and activate a 'dev' profile for development.

Hope everything is clear.

Regards

Comment: If i understand correctly i can create application-aws.yml  use it when i started app on aws server.  
java -Dspring.profiles.active=aws -jar target/my-app.jar

Thanks, i'll read how to do it with Elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Yes, Exactly, If you want to try i posted a simple proof of concept : https://github.com/fugerit79/server-port-demo , hope it helps. See you

Comment: The proper way - as I already pointed out - would be to pull the information from the environment, i.e. bind `server.port` to an environment variable, possibly with a default value if not set: `server.port="${SERVER_PORT:5000}"` (the syntax for yaml is analogous).

Comment: @Turing85 not required - Spring Boot pulls variables from the environment by default. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.2/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config

Comment: @Turing85 yes you are generally right. But since the release of Spring boot 3 and the merge with spring native project, if you want for instance build a native image or executable for Aws lamda or gcp functions, it is required to bind everything at build time.  There are some advantages of native builds on serveless infrastructure where configuration must be tougher in a slight different way.  As native is recently my default I was giving an option that would work in that scenario too. This is why I was suggesting to default configuration to production and customize the local one.

Comment: @Matteo yes, I know that. But why do you bring it up? OP did not talk about AOT compilation.

Comment: @Turing85 Just saying that I know technically there other way to achieve what was asked. But recently I am trying to thinking at solutions that would work on AOT context too. Which is becoming more and more popular. Especially in serveless contexts. I have been to the spring IO in Barcellona in May and it was a main topic. I don't want to go off topic but I found especially interesting this talk https://youtube.com/watch?v=8umoZWj6UcU&si=4V5BMj-6Ohi5YQYY

Comment: @Matteo Again: what is the relevance to the post? OP did not mention serverless. And the externalization has nothing to do with AOT compatibility. I do not see, for example, why the http port should be compile-time fixed for AOT compilation. For quarkus, at least, it is not compile-time fixed. And we do not want to fixate everything at compile-time. This would be unbelievable impractical if, for example, database configuration (especially URL, username and password) were compile-time fixed. Last time I checked, this was not necessary in spring-native, and I doubt it is now.

Comment: @Turing85 again, I think we just providing two diffrent solutions, both working. And I was pointing out that one solution (mine) would work in serverless schenario while the solution (your) is of course more direct. Can we agree on it? Or we just agree we disagree and stop this talk ok? ;)